# MySpace Integration with iPhone

Tags: iphone, social-networking, myspace

I made an iPhone application in which I have to implement myspace integration. I have created myspace application using developer.myspace.com.

And I am getting APPLICATION_SCHEME, CONSUMER_KEY & APPLICATION_ID using that application created. That I am using in my application to update status. I am not getting the following details: 
(i) CONSUMER_SECRET
(ii) ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY
(iii) ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
(iv) PERSON_ID

And whenever I update status on myspace it is giving error 401 which means authentication failed. So, Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

The reference application which I have created is [here](https://github.com/myspace/myspace-iphone-sdk).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-->You need to **register a unique URL Type** within your **.plist file.**

-->  **Make sure** to set the **UrlScheme property** of the context to the **same value** you are using **in** the **.plist** when you instantiate the MySpace class. This will allow the SDK to create an appropriate callback URL that will fire off your application when the user has authenticated. **PLEASE DO NOT USE THE DEFAULT URLSCHEME.**

-->You can check if the user is logged in by calling [mySpace isLoggedIn]

-->This checks if your app has an Access Token associated with the user for Offsite applications (Onsite applications do not need an Access Token, hence checking if they are logged in is mute).